# Unable to locate package ros-indigo-sbpl

Tags: ros, sbpl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello ..

I'm trying to install SBPL from pre-built binary package using this command 'sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-sbpl"

but it seem there is an error "E: Unable to locate package ros-indigo-sbpl" .. I tried to update apt-get but the problem is still not solved

what shall i do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198004/unable-to-locate-package-ros-indigo-sbpl/) by [hiba](https://answers.ros.org/users/20744/hiba/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-11-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Per the [sbpl wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/sbpl) and the [Indigo buildfarm status page](http://www.ros.org/debbuild/indigo.html), SBPL is not yet released into Indigo. You'll have to build it from source: https://github.com/sbpl/sbpl

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-11-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hiba](https://answers.ros.org/users/20744/hiba/) on 2014-11-23**:
thank you for replay ...
I was using the same link and i stuck in step 2 ... do you mean this step should be skipped??

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-11-23**:
Which link? There are three in my answer